# Парсер Json из готового кода

Tags: python, json, pyqt5, beautiful-soup

Нужно в готовый код добавить или же изменить код

Есть сайт, который некоторые данные подгружает через json, а у меня код был изначально парсящий html страницу просто, но потом я заметил что не соответствуют данные и как оказалось они подгружаются через json

**Ссылка сайта https://www.mechta.kz/section/smartfony/**

**Вот ссылка на json но это только одна страница видимо**
https://api.retailrocket.net/api/2.0/recommendation/popular/6126195797a528238858a1e2/?&stockId=al&categoryIds=&categoryPaths=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%2F%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%2F%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B&format=json

Отсюда мне нужно взять OldPrice и Price

**Сам код - это приложение парсящее сайты разные**

Этот код собирает данные и выгружает

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from pickle import TRUE
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



class ThreadM(QThread):
    stepChanged = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    finished = pyqtSignal(list)
    error = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url, file, HEADERS):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.file = file
        self.HEADERS = HEADERS


    def run(self):        
        self.parseM()
        
    def parseM(self):

        html = self.get_html()
        if not html:
            if html != False:
                self.error.emit(
                    f'Error: status_code={html.status_code}'
                )
            return
        
        if html.status_code == 200:
            products = []
            pages_count = self.get_pages_count(html.text)
            for page in range(1, pages_count + 1):
                self.stepChanged.emit(page, pages_count)
                
                html = self.get_html(params={'page': page})
                products.extend(self.get_content(html.text))
                self.msleep(50)
                
            self.finished.emit(products)

        else: 
            self.error.emit(f'Error: status_code={html.status_code}')

    def get_html(self, params=None):
        try:
            r = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.HEADERS, params=params)
            return r 
        except:
            self.error.emit(f'Error: Что-то пошло не так.')
            return False

    def get_pages_count(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        pagination = soup.select('span.block')
        if pagination:
            return int(pagination[-1].get_text().replace('\n', ''))
        else:
            return 1

    def get_content(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all("div", class_="hoverCard")
        
        products = []
        for item in items:
            price = item.find('div', class_='text-ts1')
            old_price = ''
            if price:
                price = price.get_text(strip=TRUE).replace(',', ' ')
            else:
                price = 'Нет в наличии'
            products.append({
                'title': item.find('div', class_='ellipsis').get_text(strip=TRUE),
                'price': price,
                'old price': old_price
            })    
        return products
```

А тут само приложение, оно скорее всего не нужно, но все же

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from Сайты.Sulpak import ThreadS
from Сайты.Mechta import ThreadM

from pickle import TRUE



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(700, 700)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(112, 112, 112);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 400, 300, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("    QPushButton{\n"
"\n"
"background: rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    height: 50px;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background: rgb(52, 148, 189)\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 320, 340, 50))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("    QLineEdit{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    background: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"    QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 3px solid rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    }")
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 240, 340, 50))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("    QLineEdit{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    background: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"    QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 3px solid rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    }")
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(175, 130, 350, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.comboBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("QComboBox{\n"
"    border-radius: 30px;\n"
"    padding-left: 140px;\n"
"    background:rgb(56, 56, 56);\n"
"    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(89, 133, 255);\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    color: #fff;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox QAbstractItemView {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    border-radius: 20px;\n"
"    background-color:rgb(56, 56, 56);\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox::drop-down {\n"
"    width: 25px;\n"
"    height: 25px;\n"
"    top: 15px;\n"
"    right: 15px;\n"
"}")
        self.comboBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
 
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 499, 400, 151))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)                                         
        self.widget.setFont(font)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background: #fff;\n"
"color: black;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Введите URL каталога"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Введите название файла"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("Form", "Sulpak"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "Sulpak"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "Мечта"))



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    HEADERS = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
        'accept' : '*/*'
    }
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn)
        self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_changed)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText('.csv')
        self.threads=[] 
        self.combo_status=0

    def on_combobox_changed(self, index):
        index = self.comboBox.currentIndex()

        if index == 0:
            self.combo_status=index
        elif index == 1:
            self.combo_status=index

    def btn(self):
        if not self.lineEdit.text() or not self.lineEdit_2.text():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните поля ввода.')
            return
        
        
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.url = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.file = self.lineEdit_2.text()

        
        if self.combo_status == 0:
            self.thread = ThreadS(self.url, self.file, self.HEADERS)
        elif self.combo_status == 1:
            self.thread = ThreadM(self.url, self.file, self.HEADERS)

        self.threads.append(self.thread)
        self.thread.stepChanged.connect(self.onStepChanged)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.save_file)
        self.thread.error.connect(self.error)
        self.thread.start()  

    def error(self, error):
        self.widget.append(error) 
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Error', error)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        
    def onStepChanged(self, page, pages_count):
        self.widget.append(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {pages_count}...')    

    def save_file(self, items):
        if self.combo_status == 0:
            self.combobox_name = "Спаршенные данные/Sulpak"
        elif self.combo_status == 1:
            self.combobox_name = "Спаршенные данные/Mechta"
        file_s=self.combobox_name +'/'+self.file
        with open(file_s, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(['Модель', 'Цена', 'Цена без скидки'])
            for item in items:
                writer.writerow([item['title'], item['price'], item['old price']])
                
        self.widget.append(f'Получено {len(items)} товаров')
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Нужна помощь более конкретная, туговато самому**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

url ='https://api.retailrocket.net/api/2.0/recommendation/popular/6126195797a528238858a1e2/?&stockId=al&categoryIds=&categoryPaths=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%2F%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%2F%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B&format=json'
titles = requests.get(url).json()
for title in titles:
     print(title['Name'], title['OldPrice'], title['Price'])
```